# Write a function to get later elements from str_split()

Tags: r, stringr

I've received raft of data sets with multiple pieces of data in a single column recently and a like the title suggests I'm trying to write a function to return some of the later split elements. Hunting around I've seen solutions on how to get just the first element, or just the last but not how to select which elements are returned. This looks like a persistent issues in these data sets so a solution that I can abstract would would be delightful.

Example:
Ideally this function would return just the binomial names of these organism, but I don't want it anchored to the back of the string as some times there is more unneeded information after the names

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <-  data.frame(id = paste0("a", 1:6),
                      Organisms = c("EA - Enterobacter aerogenes",  "EA - Enterobacter aerogenes",
                                    "KP - Klebsiella pneumoniae", "ACBA - Acinetobacter baumannii",
                                    "ENC - Enterobacter cloacae", "KP - Klebsiella pneumoniae")) 
 ## just the first element (does not allow you to select 2 elements)                    
Orgsplit_abrev <- function(x){
  sapply(str_split(x," "), getElement, 1)
}

foo %>%
  summarise(Orgsplit_abrev(Organisms))


str_split(foo$Organisms, " ")[[1]][c(3,4)]
```

Comment: What is the actual output you want here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `tail` - as there are more than one element to be returned, return as a `list` column

```
Orgsplit_abrev <- function(x){
  lapply(str_split(x," "), tail, 2)
}
```

-testing

```
foo %>%
   summarise(Orgsplit_abrev(Organisms))
Orgsplit_abrev(Organisms)
1   Enterobacter, aerogenes
2   Enterobacter, aerogenes
3    Klebsiella, pneumoniae
4  Acinetobacter, baumannii
5     Enterobacter, cloacae
6    Klebsiella, pneumoniae
```

---

Also, if we want to specify the index, create a lambda function

```
Orgsplit_abrev <- function(x){
  lapply(str_split(x," "), function(x) x[c(3, 4)])
}
```

Or may also use Extract with `[`

```
Orgsplit_abrev <- function(x){
   lapply(str_split(x," "),`[`, c(3, 4))
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun the second two solutions are what I was hoping for. I'd never seen the lambda or extract used in those ways.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split using the "-" delimiter?

```
> str_split(foo$Organisms, "-") %>% do.call('rbind', .)
     [,1]    [,2]                      
[1,] "EA "   " Enterobacter aerogenes" 
[2,] "EA "   " Enterobacter aerogenes" 
[3,] "KP "   " Klebsiella pneumoniae"  
[4,] "ACBA " " Acinetobacter baumannii"
[5,] "ENC "  " Enterobacter cloacae"   
[6,] "KP "   " Klebsiella pneumoniae"
```

tail is also a good idea, but I would use -2 instead of 2 to keep everything but the first two elements (hence it allows more messy names to be fully included):

```
Orgsplit_abrev <- function(x){
  lapply(str_split(x," "), tail, -2)
}
```

or with the lambda function

```
Orgsplit_abrev <- function(x){
  lapply(str_split(x," "), function(x) x[3:])
}
```

Comment: while I agree that the `" - "` or `tail()` would make the most sense in this specific example I think the lambda solutions are going to be the most useful for the situations I described in my post.